# How to have a variable only in one mode with CMake

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, release, cmake

I Want to create a new mode (Debug, Release and a new one) in my project. After that I will need a variable that is only used in that new mode, so I can create a variable for all and set different value for Debug/Release (i.e. 0) and for the new one (1).

How can I solve this?

*What i have:*

```
set (CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES "Release;Debug;NewConfig" CACHE STRING "Configurations" FORCE)

SET (VARIABLEX 1)

if (VARIABLEX )
   add_definitions (-DVARIABLEX )
endif (VARIABLEX )
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, adding new configuration types is not yet well supported in CMake.

Despite the CMake FAQ, looks like there is something still a bit unimplemented for this feature request. There is even an open issue for it:

- http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=5811

Monitor that bug in the CMake bug tracker to be notified as things are updated.

However, given that you would like to have different definitions for different configurations, you should see the help for the CMake target property COMPILE_DEFINITIONS and COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG (for example):

- http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#prop_tgt:COMPILE_DEFINITIONS
- http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#prop_tgt:COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_CONFIG